# Packaging a Java app. w/DB to run on client machine

Tags: java, deployment, desktop-application, derby, embedded-database

I made a simple java desktop application using embedded database.  I wanted to package all files into a single file like exe so that client can click just on one file and use the application.  I made the jar file and its working fine on my system when double clicking.  I wanted to package the DB file along with jar because the data is shown only when the DB file is in the same folder of jar file.

I came across several tools like launch4j, install4j etc. but I didn't find where to include the DB file along with the package.

Comment: If you application designed to make changes to database it is more correct to store that database inside USERHOME.

Comment: sorry can you explain.didn't get you

Comment: I mean is case your database isn't designed to be readonly it is kind of user data and it is more ideologically correct to store such kind of data to USERHOME (User's profile directory). I think you can store empty (or prepared) database and copy it to userhome one first start.

Comment: true.Didnt think of that option .yes if its not read only that would be the best way.thanks.But what if its a read only db.

Comment: There is a path available from `System.getProperty("user.home")` that is an *excellent* place to store application files that need to be both read and written (or updated).

Comment: thanks a lot .I am encountering this for the first time so please can you explain its working in detail or provide any tutorial regarding its usage?

Comment: Btw: If several users on the same PC need to modify some common data then you have to use Common Application Data instead of "user.home", which make things even more tricky...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want an installer of some description, such as [IzPack](http://izpack.org/features/). This would allow you to package both jar and database together, and install them on a client system.

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried downloading and installing IzPack will try it

Answer (score 1):

A good way to deploy rich client (e.g. Swing/AWT) apps. that require some set-up (as in, installing a DB) is by using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

JWS offers the [`ExtensionInstallerService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/ExtensionInstallerService.html) which..

..is used by an extension installer to communicate with the JNLP Client. It provides the following type of functionality:

- Access to prefered installation location, and other information about the JNLP Client
- Manipulation of the JNLP Client's download screen
- Methods for updating the JNLP Client with the installed code

Here is a [demo. of the EIS](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis) (with code, build file etc.).

Comment: thank you ..that was something i wasn't aware of.But i don't want a web support.I should take it in a pen drive and use it on client machine.